# Constrain a dynamic loaded drop down list to 12 latest entries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down list which is populated dynamically through a database. And in my drop down list a have 100 entries of year and months. But I only want to display the latest 12 months from current date. So if I have 201802 and want to show 201802 - 201702. Any have an idea how to do that?

Example code

```
<select id="myID">
<option>201802</option>
<option>201801</option>
<option>201712</option>
<option>201711</option>
...
</select>
```

My first thought was that I should check for the length and somehow constrain that to the first 12 entries. But does that work when a new entry comes in like 201803?

```
var yearMonth = $('#myID').find("OPTION").length;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do it on the server. Removing them from the client is pointless as they have to be downloaded, rendered, then removed. Alternatively you could just build the options in a loop based on the current date, although that relies on the client machine having it's date set correctly.

Comment: Also `$('myID')` should be `$('#myID')`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, use ORDER BY and LIMIT in your SQL query.
I don't know your DB field names and table names, so I'll use an example from mine:

SELECT * FROM user_activity ORDER BY user_ID DESC LIMIT 12

- ORDER BY can be ASC (ascending) or DESC (descending)
- LIMIT is to limit the results to a certain number

I'm not sure why you need to do a DB query if all you want is to calculate 12 months back from the current date. This is a needless resource use, as you can do that completely within JavaScript. I'd understand if the data being pulled wasn't sequential and predictable.